# sitemap.xml not rendered as XML document in browser

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have created an simple sitemap.xml where I followed all the information I found in https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap#xml

Unfortunately, whenever I open the sitemap in the browser, it doesn't read the data in a xml format. It shows me like it would be an unstyled website with a simple paragraph.

The output is plain text instead of the regular XML treeview of the browser.

The sitemap sourcecode is (played around with indents and left them away for the moment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>URL</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-14</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This suggests your HTTP server is delivering the sitemap with a `text/html` content type rather than an `application/xml` one.

You need to configure your server correctly.